Why does English travel "across" the country but not "through" it?
Why is it possible to say "all across the country" since we use across for flat surfaces like "across the road" and not with things that surround us similar to a tunnel. We say through a tunnel not "across".
I think "country" is something that surrounds us yet we say "all across the country". Why?

Because a country has a map and that's the link to this. You travel across the country as if it were a map.

We can travel through the countryside. But we don't travel through a plateau or through a plain but across them.  across is used with expanses.  We use through of more variegated terrain where travel goes up and down, around curves, with vegetation to our left and right, etc.  The terrain is on all sides of us, not just underfoot.

Language reveals how the speaker is regarding the thing being spoken about (perhaps subconsciously, or just out of habit from listening to other speakers).   So we can travel across a country, presenting it as an expanse that stretches from sea to sea, even though it is not flat but could have valleys and mountains and jungles and swamps and plains. To put the matter another way, in broad terms, to say "we traveled across the country" is to present it as an expanse. To say "We traveled through the country" is to present it as a place with local variation.

There probably isn't a single absolute answer to this question, because prepositions are used flexibly in a wide range of contexts.

Over the last two hundred years English has become a dominant language, spreading across/over/around/throughout the world. (But probably not through, because this hints at drilling a hole through the centre of the earth...)

We could say this:

During our holiday we travelled throughout France. (We went to many different places in different parts of the country.)

But then we might also say this:

During our holiday we travelled throughout Europe. We started in England, travelled through France and Switzerland, and finished in Italy. (now throughout applies to the many different parts of Europe, but through France might be used to suggest directional travel, passing through an area to a place on the other side. Across would also be valid here.)

So it all depends on what you want to convey with your language.

Non-Anglophone Europeans might travel through England when going to Scotland or Wales, but Anglophones in general wouldn't normally travel through England or through the USA, because they're not often "waystations" en route to some final destination.

As you learned from the recent question you asked, we use "through" when something passes in one side and out the other, while "across" means something is spread out in all directions.
So if, for example, one was traveling to different towns and cities in England, they might say "I've traveled all across England" because they've been to places spread about in that wider area. However, if a person from Wales journeyed to Scotland (two countries that are joined by England, in case you weren't aware), they might say "I went through England" because they entered at one place and exited at another.
As you can see, you may say either - but they are different meanings for different contexts.
